# Create dynamic name avatar/icon like Google

Tags: php, image, dynamic, avatar

I want to create a logo or profile avatar from first letters of name, like Google. Is there any method or service to do it?

I am tried to learn the code about make image with php but it's to hard. One time I found a website about this dynamic image text but I don't find.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy examples you will find online are going to use PHP's [imagecreate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) and [imagestring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) functions, such as this one:

https://phppot.com/php/how-to-convert-text-to-image-using-php/

Here is a quick example-code I've put together based on the above link, that creates an image similar to the Google avatars:

```
$img = imagecreate(250, 250);

$textbgcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 52, 152, 219);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

$txt = "AB";
$fontfile = "/arial.ttf";
imagettftext($img, 100, 0, 35, 170, $textcolor , $fontfile, $txt);
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
printf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/ width="100">', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
```

You will need place the `arial.ttf` fontfile in the same directory as your PHP file for this to work.

However, in most fonts that are aesthetically pleasing, letters do not have the same width. So you will find it difficult to center the text, since you can't use the same X value for the anagram "MM" and "II". I would advise you to use  a library that has extended functions like aligning text to the middle, and my bet would be on [gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text).